# Suppress browser notification in setBackgroundMessageHandler

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am building a web app that listens for FCM messsages.

I am able to read the messages in firebase message service worker with:

```
messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload) {
    console.log('Received background message', payload);
});
```

This displays a browser notification, that I want to get rid of. I have some custom logic that I want to execute on notification:

The notification data that I am sending to FCM from the server does not contain a notification parameter:

```
{ 
    "data": 
    { 
        "foo": "1",
        "bar": "2"
    },
    "to" : "device_registration_id", 
    "content_available": false 
}
```

There is a issue about this on github: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/issues/126

Some people report that `self.registration.hideNotification()` is working, but that was not the case for me.

The only way to do it was return a never resolving Promise, but that would create a memory leak, and it is a sub optimal solution:

```
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { });
```

Any proper way to do this?

Comment: Little 'Hacky', but why wont you reject the promise immediately?

Comment: @Anatsu, rejecting the promise, also produces a notification